# get specific lines in a range pattern from a text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I am attempting to search a specific part of a text file and save the information in between two key words. What does the syntax look like to allow me to save only the information in the middle? Currently my code is:

```
$awk -f strip.awk <in>out
{
Strip.awk

{
if ($0 == "<!-- start of lyrics -->")
    lyr = 1
    if ($0=="<!-- end of lyrics -->")
    lyr = 0
    if(lyr==1)
    Lyrics = lyr $0
    }
printf("%s/n", Lyrics)
>>Lyric.csv

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '/<!-- start of lyrics -->/,/<!-- end of lyrics -->/' input.txt >> Lyric.csv
```

---

This is from my copy of `"The AWK Programming Language" (1984, p23)`:

> - *pattern 1 , pattern 2 { statements }*
>   A range pattern matches each input line from a line matched by pattern 1 to the next line matched by pattern 2, inclusive; the statements are executed at each matching
>     line.
>   A range pattern cannot be part of
>     any other pattern.

To exclude `pattern 1` & `pattern 2` from the output range:

```
awk  '/pattern 1/,/pattern 2/ {if ($0 !~ /pattern 1|pattern 2/) print}' input.txt
```

Comment: Hey this is really cool.  I don't know how many times I've missed this in my copy of "The AWK Programming Language". +1 for opening my eyes.  I had to put this in a file to run it ( shell interpretation errors? ) and it includes the "start" and "end" lines in the output.

Comment: @n0741337 added some explanation.

Comment: @captcha to exclude a pattern you could shorten it to - `awk 'NR==1,/pattern 1/{next}/pattern 2/,0{next}1'`

Comment: @captcha - thanks for the extra information.  I have the revised 1988 edition, in which the "Range Patterns" section starts on page 32 and has slightly different text.

Comment: @JS웃 your code only finds the first range in a file, not more.

Answer (score 1):

This script should do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '
/<!-- start of lyrics -->/ { lyrics = 1; next }
/<!-- end of lyrics -->/ { exit }
lyrics { print }
'
```

If you call it `script.sh` then you can use it like this:

```
./script.sh < input.txt > lyrics.txt
```

This is how it works:

- `/<!-- start of lyrics -->/ { lyrics = 1; next }` : If the line matches the start "pattern", then set the `lyrics` variable and jump to the next line
- `/<!-- end of lyrics -->/ { exit }` : If the line matches the end "pattern", then exit
- `lyrics { print }` : If the `lyrics` variable is set, print the line

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "save only the information in the middle", but assuming you mean you just want to print what's between the two delimiters:

```
awk '/<!-- start of lyrics -->/{p=1}/<!-- end of lyrics -->{p=0}p{print}0' input.txt
```

ought to work.

It basically sets and resets a flag depending on whether the start/end tags have been seen, and only prints lines when the flag is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

Both `sed` and `awk` supports `regex ranges`.

```
$ cat ff
1
2
3
4
START
4
5
3
6
7
END
14
5
8
```

```
$ awk '/START/,/END/' ff
START
4
5
3
6
7
END
```

```
$ sed -n '/START/,/END/p' ff
START
4
5
3
6
7
END
```